# In which classes we are not using Log4J

Tags: log4j

In which classes we are not using Log4J? I used log4j in controller, service and Dao class. Can I use it in utility and DTO classes as well?

Answer (score 0):

In all classes we can use the log4j Except DTO.

Comment: In DTO class we are not using Log4J